# LEDs have a low glow "noise"

Tags: led, bjt

Interim conclusion edit at bottom.

I'm driving a stack of 5mm LEDs off 24volts as in the diagram below. I have four stacks of these, two have 5 white LEDs and share their base drive, one has 7 red, and one has 7 yellow and each of those is driven off a different output.

What I'm noticing is that they glow very very gently, and flicker as they do so (almost like an imitation of a candle-flame, which might be cute if I wanted it). Unfortunately, it's critical to the purpose of this design that these LEDs be *totally* dark when off.

I notice that the LEDs are not all glowing the same amount, some seem to be more alive than others (though which ones is repeatable). I guess this is because they have slightly different characteristics, and whatever current is running down that stack is intermittently enough to make the most sensitive glow while still doing nothing to the others?

Originally, the resistor and capacitor from the base to ground were not in the circuit. I first added the capacitor because I could see some high frequency (in the MHz range) noise on my scope, but that made no difference, then I added the pull-down resistor on a whim. That too made no difference. The scope shows the voltage at the bases of the transistors is essentially zero, and the noise peaks are perhaps 15 mV.

So the question is, what's causing the glowing, and how do I fix it. Is it perhaps a leakage current/noise thing in the transistor? They're 2N2222. Again, what would be a good course of action. Do I need to use a FET instead of a BJT? I went with a BJT so I could control the current through the LEDs even when a stack of them might have had significantly different forward voltages, which differences would be potentially exacerbated by having more of them. (3v3 at the base minus the 0.7 forward BE junction puts 2v6 on the 150R and should give me a pretty predictable 17 mA through the LEDs, and the worst case voltage on the transistor still results in a pretty modest power dissipation. Well, that was the plan!)

One thing I know I don't know is what is the lowest current level that will make an LED emit some level of light.

Edits: These include a little more info, and answers to some of the questions so far raised:

1. The flicker is so faint that it is undetectable unless in a dark
   room (but this matters to me!)
2. The transistors' bases are driven directly of the digital output of a NodeMCU
3. It still flickers with a hard ground on the base and the CPU removed
4. I can't put R1 between the collector and the diode, as that would lose my current control
5. There's no mains noise on the base lines. Noise is very random,
   looks very white (to the naked eye), and around 15 mV peak.
6. Putting the scope on base and then the emitter both show essentially
   0v (suggesting "low" leakage through that 150R)
7. There is between 2v and 3v2 on the various LEDs in the stack. I think this tells me that it really is a leakage current issue. I had hoped to see the collector sitting at 24 V (supply rail) but it's not, it's about +10 V.

Edit 2: Interim conclusion.
So, based on extensive and very generous help in the answers and comments, I believe this really is leakage. I have experimented a little with the idea of adding resistors across the diodes which helped some, and it's quite possible that more experimentation might have found a good solution. The circuit proposed by MicroservicesOnDDD looks fascinating, but to be honest, it's more complex than I was hoping, and I admit I've not tried it (though I might get to it at some point).

The two things that I've done at this point are:

1. I added an additional LED (making six in the white stack, and eight in the red and orange stacks). This made a distinct improvement.
2. In a burst of "crude, but effective", I added a simple relay and am now turning the 24 volt power for these LEDs off entirely when they're not wanted. The current relay is 240 volt capable, which is simply what I had in stock and so has higher current draw than it likely needs. However, it does, of course, entirely suppress the glow. So for now at least, this is my solution. Not terribly elegant, but provided the "click" that it makes when turning on isn't a problem, absolutely effective.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJafLK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So what is driving the base and how? Direct connection to a 3.3V IO pin on some device?

Comment: yes, direct from a 3v3 digital output pin on a NodeMCU / ESP8266.

Comment: Does it still happen if you disconnect the CPU? If no, then I would suspect ground noise.

Comment: Have you tried it with R1 hooked up between Q1 and D5?

Comment: "The lowest current level that will make an LED emit some level of light" doesn't exist, at least not in the form you're probably expecting it to be. In *theory*, any current at all will cause light to be emitted, right down to a single photon at a time for incredibly low currents; in *practice* it's essentially random depending on the specific LED you're looking at.

Comment: @Mattman944, I took the CPU out (it's socketed) and grounded the signal lines to the transistors. No difference :(

Comment: Transistor may be faulty, replace it and see..

Comment: @KH I can't do that, or I lose the current control effect I'm depending on (I see your thinking though :)

Comment: @Hearth I was afraid of that! Not sure where that leaves me.

Comment: @beccabecca Unlikely for four separate, but essentially identical circuits (plus they turn on and off generally fine, just off ain't off enough--and it's miniscule but matters in this application). However, this seems (from Hearth's comment) like it might be a leakage current issue, in which case the *selection* of transistor might be faulty I guess.

Comment: Is there noise (AC) on the 24 V supply? What is the voltage drop across the five LEDs? Can you put an oscilloscope on Q1's collector to see what's going on?

Comment: @Transistor no 60 Hz noise is visible. It's a very small (~15 mV) very "noise like" noise. By that I mean the scope (which has a frequency output) reads it as something between 100 kHz and 35 MHz (i.e. it's failing to lock onto anything actually repetitive). Very small, very random looking, perhaps twice the amplitude of the noise on the ground rail itself.

Comment: I note that the datasheet claims 10 uA leakage, but quotes that at Vbe of -3 V. So, I don't know what it might be at +15 mV. I'll try to estimate by putting the scope across R1.

Comment: I recreated the circuit the best I could. My 2N2222 is of unknown origin. My LEDs are modern white 5mm. At 24V, the LEDs are barely perceptible with 50 mV on the base. The emitter resistor voltage is below the threshold of my meter (1 mV), which means the LED current is less than 7 uA. At 26V, the LEDs are barely perceptible with **zero** volts on the base. At 29V, the LEDs are easily perceptible with **zero** volts on the base.

Comment: Another experiment. No transistor, 5 LEDs, and a 10k resistor. With the power supply set to 10.85 V, the LEDs are barely perceptible. The voltage across the 10k is 2 mV, corresponding to a current of 0.2 uA!

Comment: Wow, so with 10 uA leakage in the 2N2222 datasheet, I'm on a loser really!

Comment: Besides the simulation contained in my answer below, I did another simulation that calculated the leakage of all the transistors included in LTSpice XVII, with the hunch that one of the higher voltage transistors would be the winner, on the argument that if the junction can hold back a lot of voltage, when you turn it off, it will hopefully leak less.  Sure enough, the winner was the highest voltage transistor, the 2N5550, at 150 Volts.  The range of values did not seem to be indicative of significantly better performance, though, but it's worth a try at less than 25 cents at Digi-Key.

Comment: That's very helpful @MicroservicesOnDDD thank you! I'm adding some edits shortly, and one thing I did that seemed to help far more than I would have expected was adding a sixth LED. My guess is this is a related thing, since it drops the Vce by another 3 volts ish, presumably that's a similar kind of change, qualitatively, in terms of reducing the proportion of the transistor's "stopping power" that's actually being called for..

Comment: You may even be able to go to 7 LEDs.

Comment: Actually, I recall doing the math at the start of this and coming to the same conclusion. But I found that the variations in LEDs meant that while my first stack worked, the second did not. So, I backed away (I plan to make several of these, so I need the consistent performance even with variability in the components). I think, however, that I backed away too far, and that's what got me to 5 "for safety" and created the excessive glow. But turning the power rail off with a relay has certainly done the trick!

Comment: 3 years later:  A high side PNP driving the string with an added low side NPN driven as per Q1 but its collector driving the high side PNP would come close to duplicating your relay. It too has leakage when off isues but the two together should greatly improv results. Simulated in mind only. || A "sure to work" [tm] solution is to use a Q3 to short the LED string when off.   That can be driven by a low side Q4 NPN with base connected via a resistor to V_supply_low and emitter driven by input signal. Q4 low is thus on when Q1 is on and vice versa.  Shoot through voidance may need a capacitor.

Comment: I could post an answer as above if it's still useful 3 years on.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely *not* due to a flaw in the driver, or in the signal source, since
only *some* flicker. Because LED's are not absolutely identical, the voltage across each in a series string will not be equal for DC due to differing leakage currents, and for AC this would be exacerbated  by differing capacitance wihin each device and from device to ground. Therefore, a signal not providing enough voltage to light *all* could cause a few to glow feebly.

The easiest fix is to put equalizing resistors across each LED. perhaps 100 kΩ as a first try. 10 nF caps across them might also be needed, if the resistors aren't enough to make the LED strings completely dark when nominally *off*.

Comment: Interesting. That'll take a bit more time to set up the experiment, but I'll give it a go and check back.

Comment: Meantime, there is (noted now in the question) there are indeed significant forward voltages across the LEDs. Between 2 and 3.2 volts. I'll try your suggestion when I can.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my testing (see comments), the glow can be caused by transistor leakage. In my setup, the glow starts when the voltage is 26 volts (could easily vary depending on the transistor). Capacitive coupling would have a similar effect.

One 10k resistor across all 5 LEDs removes the glow in my setup. This works up to 31 V, the highest that my power supply will go. The 10k resistor will steal a few milliamps, you could try a higher value resistor if that is an issue.

This is basically what DrMoishe suggested, but only one resistor may be necessary.

Comment: I tried 10k across everything, and I believe it improved, but it's still there. My need is absurdly sensitive, since this thing must be invisible in a pitch black room to dark adapted human eyes (and they're surprisingly sensitive when actually dark adapted!).

Comment: Kudos for testing. You might need to vary the resistance a bit, either to conserve power or to diminish glow.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an LTSpice XVII circuit which (at least in simulation) does what you want:

[image: LTSpice XVII electrical circuit that answers question, at least in simulation.]

When the 3.3 voltage source is connected (representing a HIGH on your microcontroller pin) there is 17mA running through your 5-LED string.

When the 3.3 voltage source is disconnected (by deleting the little bridge inside the circle) the current running throught D1 is reportedly in the femto-amp range (40 femtoAmps).

U1 is a voltage reference used to implement a constant current sink at NPN1 using R8 and R10 as a voltage divider and current/voltage delivery to NPN1.  This is what causes the 17mA to flow.  R9 is a pull-down for when the circuit is off.

When the circuit is off, R5 pulls up PNP3 and R7 pulls up PNP4, turning them off except for current leakage.  Also, R6 pulls down NPN2, turning it off, which turns off PNP3.  Effectively, the whole circuit is off except for leakage currents.

Finally, the 10Meg resistor at R14 is a big enough drain that it takes almost all of the leakage current (in the picoAmp magnitude in simulation).  Depending on R14, which I switched back and forth from 1Meg to 10Meg, the current remaining in D1 ranges (in simulation) from +100fA to -100fA.  Placing a 10Meg potentiometer at R14 should allow you to make the LEDs completely dark.  Not really sure if D6 is necessary.  And I'm not sure if the LEDs will glow with the current going backwards (it's such a low amount at femto-Amps that it should not cause any damage).

I did not build this circuit to verify it.

Comment: That looks awesome! I shall investigate and ensure I understand it.